# Trouble with Materialize CSS

Tags: css, materialize

I am trying to add a fixed action button with social media icons on my website, however I am having trouble. I have the following code:

```
<div class="fixed-action-btn horizontal click-to-toggle">
  <a class="btn-floating btn-large red">
      <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
  </a>
  <ul>
      <li>
          <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-floating social google"><i class="fa fa-google"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-floating facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-floating github"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I am able to see the initial menu button in the bottom right (the 3 horizontal lines) but when I click it, it does not show the icons. It doesn't seem to be doing anything. I installed materialize by using npm install --save materialize-social. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you are linking to the js files as well at the end of your `</body>`. `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>`  See the HTML Setup here - https://materializecss.com/getting-started.html

Comment: thank you for the response! Its a Vue project so I dont really know how to add in the <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script> code. I tried putting that in the index.html however, that did not seem to work.